# Spring Data key-value custom queries does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-keyvalue

There is an in-memory repository class:

```
@Repository
interface InMemoryBookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, String> {
    int countByAuthor(String author);
}
```

The book model class:

```
@Value
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true, access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor
@KeySpace("books")
class Book {
    @Id
    String id;
    String title;
    String author;
    String isbn;
}
```

whenever I try to invoke this method an exception is thrown: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Query method not supported.` The version of the spring-data-keyvalue is 2.6.4 - the latest one. Any advice?

Comment: Maybe it could help to also share your Book class, Maybe also try out if findByAuthor works as expected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data JPA Redis : Cannot write custom method based query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101829/spring-data-jpa-redis-cannot-write-custom-method-based-query)

Answer (score 0):

Repositories work with Entity classes.
So my guess is, that you should annotate your Book Class with @Entity.

```
@Value
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true, access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor
@KeySpace("books")
@Entity
class Book {
    @Id
    String id;
    String title;
    String author;
    String isbn;
}
```